# Install knoppix on usb with disk utility?

Tags: usb, disk-utility, unix, bootable-disk

I have downloaded the linux distro knoppix.

I have snow leopard and i want to make a bootable usb with the above distro with the disk utility.

I put the source to be the iso of the distro and destination to be the volume of my usb.

When i click restore it throws error : invalid argument for the destination.

Anyone have any idea about that? How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a similar issue merely trying to image dmg files to external disks with Disk Utility.app. Apparently, Disk Utility would prefer that before you begin your restore that you select the disk image in the left, and under the Image menu, select "Scan Image for Restore," and after that process completes, then try the imaging operation. If you have already errored, you need to quit Disk Utility and relaunch it, or you will continue to get the same error.